# How do I design a data ingestion process in Snowflake that includes update/inserts and maintain optimum performance

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I will be ingesting about 20-years of data that includes files with millions of rows about 500 columns. Reading through Snowflake (SF) documentation I saw that I should load the files in an order that would allow SF to create the micro-partitions (MP) with metadata optimized for pruning. However, I am concerned because I will be updating previously loaded records that could ruin the integrity of the MP. Is there a best practice for handling updates? Might I at some point need to reorg the table data to regain its performance structure. Are cluster keys adequate for handling or should I consider a combination of the two. I am planning on splitting the load files into logical combinations that would also support the proper metadata definitions but am also wondering if there is preferred limit to number of columns. If there is a know best practice document please let me know. Thanks. hs

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to worry about any of that, regarding how the data is stored. Snowflake doesn’t do updates, it only inserts into the micro partitions.

Performance with updates will obviously be slower than pure inserts, but that’s a different issue.

Comment: yes but according to the literature Snowflake prunes unneeded micro partitions based on the metadata which would be efficient with initial inserts but possibly corrupted but with  random updates. Is there a strategy to account for that? What does a SQL update actually do within Snowflake storage?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “corrupted” - do you think Snowflake gets corrupted in some way if you update records? When Snowflake is “updated” it inserts a new micro-partition(s) and flags the existing  partitions as “inactive”. In any case, this discussion is academic, as all this (the management of micro-partition metadata) happens in the background and has no impact on the way you interact with Snowflake as a user

Comment: Thanks, you helped clear the process for me. No new data is stored in the old micro-partitions and updates are stored in new partitions.  However, I was planning in being as diligent as possible during the initial ingestion to assure micro-partition pruning is optimized. I am not so much concerned with my interaction but the underlying SQL optimization that occurs behind the scenes.  By "corrupted" I was was referring to the data actually being stored in the best sequential order initially and then not due to updates. I am concerned with possible time-outs when process huge tables.